# How add attribute for UsernameToken in wsse Header?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I was made WSSE Soap Header in PHP. How can I add atribute to UsernameToken tag?

Im using SoapVar to create header

```cpp
$auth = new stdClass();
$auth->Username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
    $auth->Password = new SoapVar($passdigest, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
    $auth->Nonce = new SoapVar($encoded_nonce, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
    $auth->Created = new SoapVar($created, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);

$username_token = new stdClass();
    $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns);

    $security_sv = new SoapVar(
            new SoapVar(
                    $username_token,
                    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
                    NULL,
                    $this->wss_ns,
                    'UsernameToken',
                    $this->wss_ns
                    ),
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns);
    parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
```

Result from web service is "Element passed was not a SOAPElement or is not a proper UsernameToken". The reason why is probably wrong UsernameToken tag. I need add wsu:Id attribute.

XML output from my header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://system.erif.pl/ws/schemas" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
        <ns2:UsernameToken>
            <ns2:Username>username</ns2:Username>
            <ns2:Password>lD25MlnmRXtxjT8I2cv0iMhb0yQ=</ns2:Password>
            <ns2:Nonce>MTA5NDY2Nji5OA==</ns2:Nonce>
            <ns2:Created>2019-01-12T09:19:43Z</ns2:Created>
        </ns2:UsernameToken>
    </ns2:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetReportRequest/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

UsernameToken tag should be have attribute like this

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1"
```

What is proper way to add attribute for UernameToken in SoapVar? Thank You